# A variant of the house robber problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I came across a modification of the classic house robber problem where the robber cannot rob from $l(i)$ houses on the left of $i$th house and $r(i)$ houses on the right of $i$th house. The modified version will now be as follows:

> You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that if you rob the $i$th house then you cannot rob from $l(i)$ houses on the left of $i$th house and $r(i)$ houses on the right of $i$th house (in the classical problem, $l(i) = r(i) = 1$). Given the amount the money in each house, and the arrays $l$ and $r$, what is the optimal amount to be stolen?

I believe this can be solved by dynamic programming as well. However I have been trying enough without any results and would like some help on this.

Edit 1:
l(i) and r(i) are variable i.e. different for each i.
Example:
House values: 1 3 7 3 7
L array:      0 0 2 2 2
R array:      3 0 1 0 0

The answer is 10, which is obtained by selecting the 2nd and 5th house. To further clarify l(i) and r(i), take the 3rd house for example. l is 2, means that 2 houses on the left cannot be selected (houses 1st and 2nd), whereas r is 1, meaning 1 house on the right cannot be selected (4th house)
*Note: The convention for numbering used is, first house is i=1, second is i=2 and so on.*

Comment: You can do something like:
$DP[i] = max(DP[i - 1], DP[i - l(i) - 1] + money[i])$

Comment: Mind giving an example?

Comment: Are l(i) and r(i) arrays? Or a constant like l(i) = r(i) = k?

Comment: Added an edit to clarify the two doubts.